# Bokeh Line Chart not displaying Lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, bokeh

I am trying to create an app that would display some charts based on chosen item for an average monthly data, like "6/2023", "7/2023". I have the code which is working and I can see output in my terminal, but the line graph won't work, just a blank page, and looks like it is not receiving my data. Please help

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

```
def line(request):
    items = Item.objects.values_list('item', flat=True).distinct()
    item = request.GET.get('item', 'Drink')
    data = Item.objects.filter(item=item).annotate(
        month=F('date__month'),
        year=F('date__year')
    ).values(
        'month',
        'year'
    ).annotate(
        avg_price=Avg('price')
    ).order_by(
        'year',
        'month'
    )

    item_years = [f"{k['month']}/{k['year']}" for k in data]
    item_price = [f"{v['avg_price']}" for v in data]

    cds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(item_years=item_years, item_price=item_price))
    fig = figure(height=500, sizing_mode="stretch_width", title=f"{item} GDP")
    fig.title.align = 'center'
    fig.title.text_font_size = '1.5em'
    fig.yaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="$0.0a")

    fig.circle(source=cds, x='item_years', y='item_price', size=12)
    fig.line(source=cds, x='item_years', y='item_price', line_width=2)

    tooltips = [
        ('Year', '@item_years'),
        ('Price', '@item_price')
    ]
    fig.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips))

    script, div = components(fig)
    context = {
        'items': items,
        'item': item,
        'script': script,
        'div': div,
    }

    if request.htmx:
        return render(request, 'analysis/partials/gdp-bar.html', context)

    return render(request, 'analysis/line.html', context)
```

```
<div class="row">
        <div id="linechart" class="col-10">
            {% include 'analysis/partials/gdp-bar.html' %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
                <label>Product</label>
                <select id="select-year"
                        class="custom-select"
                        name="item"
                        autocomplete="off"
                        hx-get="{% url 'linechart' %}"
                        hx-target="#linechart">

                    {% for c in items %}
                        <option value="{{c}}"
                        {% if item == c %} selected {% endif %}>{{c}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
```

I tried to display data in line graph, it worked if I used only year or month data, but not both month and yea.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You are putting string data in to the CDS, that means all the data is treated as categorical factors, and you woudl need to define a categorical range as descrbed in https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/topics/categorical.html But presumably you don't actually want that, in which case you should put the data in the CDS as actual timestamps and numbers.

Comment: @bigreddot I was using "item_years = [d.date for d in data]" first, it gives me the data back in terminal but it doesn't create line graph too. It llso worked if i do ""item_years = [d.date.year for d in data]"  and it works but showing only year. But how to show year and month? Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score -1):

If I were you, I would return data in JSON format for each array of data and use chart.js(the latest version).